# Mysql - php upload data - error - 1366 Incorrect String value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a .csv file that I need to upload to the database. There is already an existing PHP script, that parses that data and inserts it into several database tables and this has been working fine. The latest csv file is giving me errors.

I cant get myself to fix this. This is simple English Text with no special characters but I keep getting errors on certain rows.

This is an example of one such row

```
It is an investment strategy that aims to balance risk and reward
```

This is the error I get while uploading

```
ERROR=1366-Incorrect string value: '\xA0strat...' for column 'question' at row 1
```

The table charset is UTF-8 and the column question is of type TEXT

I'm running the PHP script on Windows command prompt - I have a feeling it has something to do with that. But on all previous occasions, for other CSV files - the php script was running on Windows itself.

Now when I type the above English text in notepad and insert it in CSV file - it works fine - but I have over 500 rows that are giving this error and I cannot keep typing each line in notepad and then pasting it in CSV.

*** *EDIT* *************
This is the error producing code

```
foreach($question_array as $question) 
{
   //INSERT QUESTION  table
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO adl_question (question) VALUES ('".$question."')",$con);
   echo 'ERROR='.mysql_errno($con).'-'.mysql_error($con);
   $question_id = mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Any insights
Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: It looks like the file was not encoded in UTF-8.  The byte `0xA0` (perhaps intended to represent [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm), a non-breaking space) in that location leads to an invalid UTF-8 encoding (U+00A0 is encoded in UTF-8 as `0xC2A0`).

Comment: @Ron - I will add some code - but its standard insert query in php

Comment: @eggyal - thanks for the info - anything that can be done at my end to convert that to UTF-8

Comment: First thing is to find out what encoding the file is currently in.  How was it produced?

Comment: @eggyal - unfortunate I don't have that info - the file was dropped at an ftp location - I will have to contact the business folks who will have no clue about it

Comment: @Brendan: Given that the OP doesn't know what encoding the 'bad' text is in, I'm not sure how your answer helps..?

Comment: Given that he's been handed the CSV from "business folks" (as my data was) I have assumed it came from Excel or Access. I made an educated guess as to the encoding, which is almost certainly Windows. The problem is that a CSV does not have any encoding headers, being plain text, so a CSV file with windows encoded text will cause errors when trying to simply insert into a UTF-8 database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem while doing data conversion recently. What you need to do is use iconv to read it explicitly as WINDOWS-1250 (or whatever character encoding the 'bad' text is) and then convert back to UTF-8.

```
<?php 
$string = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $badString);
?>
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php for more information.

If you need to do this for an entire file, you can use this function (that I did not write):

```
<?php 
function utf8_fopen_read($fileName) {
    $fc = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($fileName));
    $handle=fopen("php://memory", "rw");
    fwrite($handle, $fc);
    fseek($handle, 0);
    return $handle;
}
?>
```

And then implement it as so:

```
<?php 
if (($handle = utf8_fopen_read("mycsv.csv")) !== FALSE) {
    
    while($file = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        $csv[] = $file;
    }
    
    foreach($csv as $row) {
        // run insert here
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Rather than doing all of this, one could just inform MySQL of the encoding of the file with the `CHARACTER SET` clause to a [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) command: e.g. `LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/mycsv.csv' INTO TABLE adl_question CHARACTER SET latin1 ...`

Comment: I personally would not trust MySQL to handle the data conversion, but your solution might work. I think, however, he is trying to format his data before he inserts it, so it may be a moot point anyway...

Comment: MySQL just uses libiconv itself, so I don't see why it should be any less reliable.  If anything, it's usually better to use tools that already exist than attempt rolling one's own.  Plus, `LOAD DATA` is significantly ([the manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-speed.html) around 20 times) faster than invoking an `INSERT` statement for each row.

Comment: That's true. Normally I just print out the insert statement and run them all using `mysql ... < data.sql`

Comment: @brendan - your solution seems to solve the problem - thanks a lot - It wouldn't have occurred to me at all - appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

The error string is indicating that there are non-ascii chars in the text.  For example, char \xA0 will show up as white space in most editors, but is outside the ascii range.  In your example, there must be one of those chars right before the word 'strategy'.

A good hex editor will show you what the characters actually are in your strings.  I use notepad++ to view troublesome text, and you have to enable special char viewing.